# How can I define a global variable in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file, `f.py`:

```
def func():
    if 'x' not in globals():
        setattr(f, 'x', 0)
    global x
    x += 10
    print x
```

I am in an interactive session:

```
>>> import f
>>> f.func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

How should I modify `func` to define `x` if it is not already defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func():
    global x

    if 'x' not in globals():
        x = 0

    x += 10

    print(x)
```

Comment: This is not working `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
`

Comment: @Cris: It's working perfectly fine for me: http://codepad.org/U4UkFRt9. (I realize that isn't quite your same situation, but a local test verifies such a result.) Could you please provide exactly what code it is you are currently testing, and perhaps your version of Python as well?